# nan values when creating a pd.Series through a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, series

Assume we have the following dataframe

```
ap_comp = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Troll', 'Legolas'],'Code': [111, 222]})
```

and I passed it through the following function

```
a_mapping = pd.Series(apcompl['Code'], index=apcompl['Name']).to_dict()
```

my question is why the a_mapping returns as

```
{'Troll': nan, 'Legolas': nan}
```

why the nan appears? Should' t it be the following

```
{'Troll': 111, 'Legolas': 222}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have NaNs because of index alignment. The Series you pass in has an index that is different from the values passed as index, internally the constructor performs a reindexing, which gives NaN.

You would have needed to pass raw values (with `.tolist()`, `.values` or `.to_numpy()`) to the constructor, not a Series:

```
a_mapping = pd.Series(ap_comp['Code'].tolist(), index=ap_comp['Name']).to_dict()
```

But, much better, use:

```
a_mapping = ap_comp.set_index('Name')['Code'].to_dict()
```

output:

```
{'Troll': 111, 'Legolas': 222}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the feedback. Indeed once I made the changes it worked. However, how did you figure out it has different index? I mean in the future how can I spot it that the indices are different?

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to [mozway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73784773/7109869) (where he indicates the reason why OP is having the problem and presents one solution, and one alternative path), one can also do it as follows

```
a_mapping = dict(zip(ap_comp['Name'], ap_comp['Code']))

[Out]: 
{'Troll': 111, 'Legolas': 222}
```

I find that the combination between [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (which are [Python's Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions)) are quite convenient for this specific use cases (generating dictionaries from keys and values).